# including Rolebase Authentication after user sign in- beginner

Tags: c#

I have 2 controllers which has various authorization controls. For instance: `AdministrationController` can only be accessed by `Administrators`, and `SalaryController` can only be accessed by `Managers`.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public class AdministrationController : Controller
{
}
[Authorize(Roles = "Manager")]
public class SalaryController : Controller
{
}
```

The problem I have is How can I assign a Logged-in User to one of the 2 `Roles` ?

The psedocode is as follows:

If Logged-in user's user-type is Administrator. Then assign him the Role Administrator.

If Logged-in user's user-type is Manager. Then assign him the Role Manager.

Appreciate if someone can someone help me out here

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're using MVC core or an older version, and so how you sign in your users. But if it is claims based, then the log in will be something like this (with default cookie authentication):

```
var yourUser = *UserPostedFromView*;
var rememberMe = true;

...validate credentials here

var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, yourUser.Username));
...add other claims
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = rememberMe });
```

Now your user is signed in with a claim for their username.

In order for them to pass the `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` check, they will need a claim with that role. So in the above where it says `...add other claims` you can add

```
...If Logged-in user's user-type is Administrator
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator"));
```

That last line is how the claim is added that your user has the Administrator role and allows them to get into controller methods that have the `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` attribute.

Comment: I am authenticating the user via token, When the user is in valid state I need to assign a user-role to it.